# What is the smallest positive period of the fractional part function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R:x \to\{x \}$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is $1$ the smallest positive period of the fractional part function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R:x \to\{x \}$ ?

Comment: That's easy to check. Suppose $0 < p < 1$. Is there an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\{x\} \neq \{x+p\}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer: $\{1-p \}=1-p-[1-p]=1-p$ ; $\{ 1-p+p \}=0 \ne 1-p$ ; am I correct ?

Comment: Yes. I'd have taken $x = 0$, but yours works too.